# Show that a specific tensor product of fields is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, tensor-products, function-fields

> If $k$ is a finite field, $\bar{k}$ its algebraic closure and $K/k$ a finitely generated field extension of transcendence degree $1$ so that $k$ is algebraically closed in $K$, show that $R=K\otimes_k \bar{k}$ is a finitely generated field extension of $\bar{k}$ of transcendence degree $1$.

I'm heaving a problem with proving this statement. I read a proof that says it suffices to show that R is a domain, but I don't know why and I also didn't quite understand the proof that it is a domain.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

The proof was like this:

It's sufficient to show that $R^\prime=K\otimes_kk^\prime$ is a domain for every finite extension $k^\prime/k$.
$R^\prime$ is a product of fields and if $R^\prime$ is not a field then the idempotent elements generate a finite $k^\prime$-algebra in $R^\prime$ of the $k^\prime$-dimension >1. With Galois-Descent and Galoisgroup $G$ of $k^\prime/k$ we get a finite $k$-algebra in K with the $k$-dimension >1. This is a contradiction since k is relatively closed in K.

I only know the Galois-Descent as it is shown in S. Bosch, Algebra. I don't understand why the $k$-algebra is an $k$-algebra. I know it is a $k$-vectorspace but I can't see how it follows with Bosch that it is also an algebra.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific which part of the proof you do not understand.

Comment: As stated it is false.

Comment: @Mohan: You were right, I edited and now k is algebraically closed in K.

Comment: @asdq One thing that I don't understand is why R is a field if it is a domain.

Comment: It is enough to show it is a domain because in this case $R/K$ is integral: every element of $R$ is root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $K$(because $\bar{k}/k$ has this property) and it is an easy exercise to conclude that every element has an inverse, about why $R$ is a domain perhaps it is better to give a little more detail about the proof so we can help you understand it.

Comment: Thank you so far.